# Simulating a Random Walk

Tags: r, random-walk

Xn can take values of -1 or 1 each with a probability of 0.5. And Sn= Sn-1 + Xn How can I compute
the partial sum observed at time n given by Sn = X1 + X2 + : : : + Xn. I'm trying to simulate a random walk here.
I did the following but I'm not exactly sure it's right:

```
rw <- function(n){
    x=numeric(n)
    xdir=c(TRUE, FALSE)
    step=c(1,-1)
    for (i in 2:n)
    if (sample(xdir,1)) {
        x[i]=x[i-1]+sample(step,1)
    } else {
        x[i]=x[i-1]
    }
    list(x=x)
}
```

Please Help!

Comment: You may also check [this article](https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-plot-of-250-random-walks/) on R-bloggers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is just to explain why your code did not work.  @jake-burkhead gave the way you should actually write the code.

In this code, you only make a step half of the time.  This is because you are sampling from `xdir` to decide if you move or not.  Instead, I would recommend you the following inside your loop:

```
for(i in 2:n){
  x[i] <- x[i - 1] + sample(step, 1)
}
```

The `sample(step, 1)` call decides if the walk moves `1` or `-1`.

To compute the partial sums, you can use `cumsum()` after you generate `x`.  The result will be a vector of the partial sums at a given point in the walk.

Comment: Thanks! But where would I include the "i" in my loop?

Comment: You're welcome.  I was going to change `i` to `step` but was not consistent.  I fixed the code.

Comment: It would be nice to add the definition of `step = c(-1,1)` to your code snippet.

Answer (score 50):

You can also do this really concisely and efficiently with `cumsum`

```
set.seed(1)

n <- 1000
x <- cumsum(sample(c(-1, 1), n, TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: imo this is the way to do it -- in addition to being much faster due to vectorization (44x faster on a 1000000-length walk on my computer), it's a 1-liner.

Comment: Why would you sample `c(-1,1)` instead of a normal distribution `rnorm(10000,0,1)`? I guess that would be a much better equivalent of white noise.

Comment: @pieterbons the question asked about a random walk where each step can be -1 or +1

Answer (score 4):

This post addresses timings of various base R methods for this calculation. This post is inspired by comments to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883887/simulate-a-random-walk-with-purrr-in-r) and the comment of @josilber in the post to the fastest method posted by Jake Burkhead.

Below, a variety of methods are used to calculate the random walk. To accomplish this, each function pulls 1000 values of either 1 or -1 as defined in `fnc` below. The timing test uses `microbenchmark` with 1000 replications for each method.

```
fnc <- function(n) sample(c(1L, -1L), n, replace=TRUE)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(all=cumsum(fnc(1000L)),
      reduce=Reduce("+", fnc(1000L), accumulate=TRUE),
      laplyRpCln=cumsum(unlist(lapply(rep.int(1L, 1000L), fnc))),
      laplyRpAn=cumsum(unlist(lapply(rep.int(1L, 1000L), function(x) fnc(1L)))),
      laplySqAn=cumsum(unlist(lapply(seq_len(1000L), function(x) fnc(1L)))),
      saplyRpCln=cumsum(sapply(rep.int(1L, 1000L), fnc)),
      saplyRpAn=cumsum(sapply(rep.int(1L, 1000L), function(x) fnc(1L))),
      saplySqAn=cumsum(sapply(seq_len(1000L), function(x) fnc(1L))),
      vaplyRpCln=cumsum(vapply(rep.int(1L, 1000L), fnc, FUN.VALUE=0)),
      vaplyRpAn=cumsum(vapply(rep.int(1L, 1000L), function(x) fnc(1L), FUN.VALUE=0)),
      vaplySqAn=cumsum(vapply(seq_len(1000L), function(x) fnc(1L), FUN.VALUE=0)),
      replicate=cumsum(replicate(1000L, fnc(1L))),
      forPre={vals <- numeric(1000L); for(i in seq_along(vals)) vals[i] <- fnc(1L); cumsum(vals)},
      forNoPre={vals <- numeric(0L); for(i in seq_len(1000L)) vals <- c(vals, fnc(1L)); cumsum(vals)},
      times=1000)
```

Here,

- "all" uses the suggestion of Jake Burkhead, `cumsum` and pulling the sample all at once.
- "reduce" pulls the sample at once, but uses `Reduce` to perform the summation.
- laplyRpCln uses `lapply` and `unlist` to return a vector and iterates through 1000 instances of 1, calling the function directly by name.
- laplyRpAn differs in using an anonymous function.
- laplySqAn uses an anonymous function and creates the iterating variable with `seq` rather than `rep`.
- saplyRpCln, laplyRpAn, laplySqAn are the same as laplyRpCln, etc except that `sapply` is called instead of `lapply`/`unlist`.
- vaplyRpCln, etc are the same as laplyRpCln, etc except that `vapply` is used in place of `lapply`/`unlist`.
- replicate is a call to `replicate`, where the default is simplify=TRUE.
- forPre uses a `for` loop that pre-allocates the vector and the fills it in.
- forNoPre uses a `for` loop that creates an empty `numeric(0)` vector and then uses `c` to concatenate to that vector.

This returns

```
Unit: microseconds
       expr      min         lq        mean     median         uq      max neval     cld
        all   25.634    31.0705    85.66495    33.6890    35.3400 49240.30  1000 a      
     reduce  542.073   646.7720   780.13592   696.4775   750.2025 51685.44  1000  b     
 laplyRpCln 4349.384  5026.4015  6433.60754  5409.2485  7209.3405 58494.44  1000   c e  
  laplyRpAn 4600.200  5281.6190  6513.58733  5682.0570  7488.0865 55239.04  1000   c e  
  laplySqAn 4616.986  5251.4685  6514.09770  5634.9065  7488.1560 54263.04  1000   c e  
 saplyRpCln 4362.324  5080.3970  6325.66531  5506.5330  7294.6225 59075.02  1000   cd   
  saplyRpAn 4701.140  5386.1350  6781.95655  5786.6905  7587.8525 55429.02  1000     e  
  saplySqAn 4651.682  5342.5390  6551.35939  5735.0610  7525.4725 55148.32  1000   c e  
 vaplyRpCln 4366.322  5046.0625  6270.66501  5482.8565  7208.0680 63756.83  1000   c    
  vaplyRpAn 4657.256  5347.2190  6724.35226  5818.5225  7580.3695 64513.37  1000    de  
  vaplySqAn 4623.897  5325.6230  6475.97938  5769.8130  7541.3895 14614.67  1000   c e  
  replicate 4722.540  5395.1420  6653.90306  5777.3045  7638.8085 59376.89  1000   c e  
     forPre 5911.107  6823.3040  8172.41411  7226.7820  9038.9550 56119.11  1000      f 
   forNoPre 8431.855 10584.6535 11401.64190 10910.0480 11267.5605 58566.27  1000       g
```

Notice that the first method is clearly the fastest. This is followed by pulling the full sample at once and then using `Reduce` to perform the summation. Among the `*apply` functions, the "clean" versions, using the name of the function directly seem to have a minor performance improvement, and the `lapply` version seems to be on par with `vapply`, but given the range of values, this conclusion is not entirely straightforward. `sapply` appears to be the slowest, though the method of function call dominates the type of `*apply` function.

The two `for` loops performed the worst, and the pre-allocation `for` loop outperforming `for` loop growing with `c`.

Here, I'm running a patched version of 3.4.1 (patched roughly August 23, 2017) on openSuse 42.1.

Please let me know if you see any mistakes and I'll fix them as soon as I can. Thanks to Ben Bolker for prodding me to investigate the final function more, where I found a couple of bugs.

Comment: why is `forNoPre` 3x faster than `forPre`? That seems really fishy.

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you, this prompted a second look. I had neglected to store the results of each additional draw  (`c(vals, fnc(1L))` instead of `vals <- c(vals, fnc(1L))` in the forNoPre runs. And an even worse bug where I was trying to `seq_along`  a vector of length 0...

Answer (score 0):

Here one way of doing it.

```
GenerateRandomWalk <- function(k = 250,initial.value = 0) {
  # Add a bionomial at each step
  samples = rbinom(k,1,0.5)
  samples[samples==0] = -1
  initial.value + c(0, cumsum(samples))
}
```